# Passing values between in and out contracts in D

Tags: d

I'm new to D. I'm starting to utilize contracts and I think they are wonderful. However, I can't seem to find in the documentation where I can store local values available to the contracts like so...

```d
struct Vector2(T) {
    T x = 0;
    T y = 0;

    Vector2!T opBinary(string op)(const ref Vector2!T rhs)
        if(op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "*" || op == "/")
    in {
        T prevx = this.x;
        T prevy = this.y;
    }
    out {
        static if(isFloatingPoint!T) {
            assert(mixin("approxEqual(this.x, prevx"~op~"rhs.x)"));
            assert(mixin("approxEqual(this.y, prevy"~op~"rhs.y)"));
        } else {
            assert(mixin("this.x == (prevx"~op~"rhs.x)"));
            assert(mixin("this.y == (prevy"~op~"rhs.y)"));
        }
    }
    body {
        Vector2!T ret;
        mixin("ret.x = this.x"~op~"rhs.x;");
        mixin("ret.y = this.y"~op~"rhs.y;");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I need the value of x and y before the body is executed so that I may correctly verify the result in the out block. However, prevx and prevy obviously cannot travel between scopes. Is there some method of passing data between the in and out contracts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, there isn't. Best you can do is store it in some other variable on the outside and you can hit trouble there with recursion and such :(

Comment: Another possiblity is to write asserts inside the body. For optimisation one could wrap this in static if's and check for some command line defined parameter or if it isn't built in release mode or soomething.

Comment: Yeah, but then it isn't really a contract anymore, it is just another regular assertion. Contracts have special syntax outside the body because they are actually inherited and checked outside the body. In a subclass, if you override the body, all checks inside it are overridden too... but with in contracts, the old ones are still there and checked as `super.in_contract || this.in_contract` - the interface's contract still counts (because you can still use the class through the interface!). Same with out contracts, but it is `&&` there. This fact differs from body... and makes var storage hard.